# Base64 encode script for user data (AWS SDK for Java API)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data

How do I turn what was in a bash script file into a base64 encoded string that will work with Amazon's Java API? This code expresses what I'm trying to do but results in an exception:

...Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Invalid BASE64 encoding of user data (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue...

```
String startupUserData = "#!/bin/bash cd /home/ubuntu/myTestDir; mvn test -PmyBuild";

startupUserData = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(startupUserData.getBytes());

runRqst.withImageId(_computerAmi)
        .withInstanceType(instanceSize)
        .withMinCount(hwRequest.numHwComputers)
        // .withMaxCount(Utils.MAX_EC2_INSTANCES_AT_A_TIME) // NOT THIS
        .withMaxCount(hwRequest.numHwComputers)
        .withKeyName(_keyName)
        .withSecurityGroups(_securityGroup)
        .withUserData(startupUserData);
ec2.runInstances(runRqst);
```

Edit:
com.amazonaws.util.Base64.encodeAsString() quells the exception but the script still doesn't execute. How should the string be formatted? Should there be carriage returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For encoding you need to use Encoding class provided by Amazon.

i.e **amazon.webservices.common.Encoding**

It contains API EncodeBase64() which returns you encoded data.

```
public static String EncodeBase64(byte[] rawData) {
 return Base64.encodeBytes(rawData);
}
```

Comment: Got a link or the full class path?

Comment: Check this out. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/AuthBase64Encoding.html

Answer (score 2):

Had problem to use answers above. My solution was that I imported

```
import com.amazonaws.util.Base64;
```

and then

```
String initScript = "sudo -i apt-get install docker.io";

RunInstancesRequest run_request = new RunInstancesRequest()
                .withImageId(ami_id)
                .withInstanceType(InstanceType.T2Micro)
                .withMaxCount(1)
                .withMinCount(1)
                .withUserData(Base64.encodeAsString(initScript.getBytes()));
```

Answer (score 0):

com.amazonaws.util.Base64.encodeAsString works for me.  I use \n to separate multi-lin. You can also verify it at /var/lib/cloud/instance/user-data.txt the same http://169.254.169.254/user-data returns.